# Is reed switch sensitive to DC magnetic field?

Tags: switches, electromagnetism, wire, reed-switch

How would I know if a reed switch in parallel to a DC wire in which is flowing current can be closed by the magnetic field produced? If yes, what's the minimum current required?

Answer (score 2):

> How would I know if a reed switch in parallel to a DC wire in which is flowing current can be closed by the magnetic field produced?

You need to create a reed relay to create a strong enough magnetic field *along* the reeds. Running a wire alongside the reed switch won't work.

[image]

*Source: [How to Choose the Right Relay](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/2774/en/) by National Instruments.*

A minimum number of ampere-turns will be required and this must be calculated from the manufacturer's datasheet. Hamlin's [Application Note AN102A](http://www.hamlin.com/specSheets/AN102A-Ampere-turn_versus_mT_and_Gauss.pdf) may be of interest along with some other links below.

[image]

> ... what's the minimum current required?

It's the *product* of the current and the number of turns. More turns means less current is required.

**Links**

[Reed Sensors vs. Hall Effect Sensors](http://www.digikey.ie/Web%20Export/Supplier%20Content/Meder_374/PDF/MEDER_Reed_Sensors_vs._Hall_Effect_Sensors.pdf) by Medor Electronic.

[Basic Electrical Parameters of Reed Switch
Products](http://www.digikey.ie/Web%20Export/Supplier%20Content/Meder_374/PDF/MEDER_Parameters_of_Reed_Switch.pdf) by Meder Electronic.

Comment: Thx for the photo additions.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum current through a wire to close a reed relay is specified by the manufacture, often as ampere-turns minimum. A large reed relay may need 100 ampere-turns for the switch to close (100 amps if only a single turn), but if you have a coil with 10,000 turns you only need about 10mA which with 40awg wire works out to about 24vdc across the coil.
 I have worked with several small and large reed relays and the ampere-turns is the key. Usually when you buy a reed relay the datasheet offers suggested coils to use, and their datasheets list the maximum current/voltage for that coil, assuming they are not a single assembly.
 *Reed relays ignore close wires that do not wrap at least 1 turn around the body of the relay*, with the center of the relay being the most sensitive area. *Wires across the middle running at right angles to the relay with high current are more likely to cause a false closure of the relay*, or relay chatter if the current is AC.
By combining the datasheets for the relay and the coil you should have the minimum pull-in current, typical operating current, and maximum safe current, along with the DC voltages possible at each current level.